# Create index from pandas DataFrame Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this (where 'ID' is the name of the index):

```
                      VAF
ID  
chr1-115227855-T-A  0.002491
chr1-115227855-T-C  0.005449
chr1-115227856-C-A  0.000466
chr1-115227856-C-G  0.000311
chr1-115227856-C-T  0.002331
```

And a second DataFrame that looks like this:

```
    Chrom   Loc WT  Var Change  ConvChange  AO  DP  VAF IntEx   Gene    Upstream    Downstream  Individual
0   chr1    115227855   T   C   T>C T>C 43  16155   0.00266171  TIII    TIIIa   NaN NaN 1
1   chr1    115227856   C   T   C>T C>T 25  16179   0.00154521  TIII    TIIIa   NaN NaN 1
2   chr1    115227857   C   T   C>T C>T 20  16178   0.00123625  TIII    TIIIa   NaN NaN 1
3   chr1    115227858   A   T   A>T T>A 29  16178   0.00179256  TIII    TIIIa   NaN NaN 1
4   chr1    115227880   C   T   C>T C>T 18  16150   0.00111455  TIII    TIIIa   NaN NaN 1
```

I would like to make the second DataFrame look like the first. I have tried setting a new index like this:

```
df2.set_index(['Chrom','Loc','WT','Var']).VAF
```

But this just give me a multiple indexed DataFrame.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First join columns together to `Series`, [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), change index name by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and select column `VAF` by double `[]` to one column `DataFrame`:

```
s = df['Chrom'] + '-' + df['Loc'].astype(str) + '-' +  df['WT'] + '-' + df['Var']

df1 = df.set_index(s).rename_axis('ID')[['VAF']]
print (df1)
                         VAF
ID                          
chr1-115227855-T-C  0.002662
chr1-115227856-C-T  0.001545
chr1-115227857-C-T  0.001236
chr1-115227858-A-T  0.001793
chr1-115227880-C-T  0.001115
```

Comment: This is likely to be much faster by avoiding `apply`.

Answer (score 6):

### `apply` a `format_map`

```
fmt = '{Chrom}-{Loc}-{WT}-{Var}'.format_map
df[['VAF']].set_index(df.apply(fmt, 1).rename('ID'))

                         VAF
ID                          
chr1-115227855-T-C  0.002662
chr1-115227856-C-T  0.001545
chr1-115227857-C-T  0.001236
chr1-115227858-A-T  0.001793
chr1-115227880-C-T  0.001115
```

---

### one-line

because it's cool `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

```
df[['VAF']].set_index(df.apply('{Chrom}-{Loc}-{WT}-{Var}'.format_map, 1).rename('ID'))
```

---

### Explanation

Create a function that takes a dictionary and passes its key:value pairs as parameters to used in a formatting string.  Notice that `'Loc'` can be `str` or `int` as `format`/`format_map` uses the string representation.

```
fmt = '{Chrom}-{Loc}-{WT}-{Var}'.format_map
```

Make a new series object by applying the function to each row of `df` using `df.apply` with `axis=1`.  In this case, each row will be passed as a `pandas.Series` and can be processed in a dictionary context.  That's perfect for `format_map`.  I'll end up renaming the series to `'ID'` to match OP's output.

```
idx = df.apply(fmt, 1).rename('ID')
```

Now if we use a `pandas.Series` within a `set_index`, Pandas will align the existing index with the index of the passed series... which is fine.

Use a **double** square bracket to slice the columns `[['VAF']]` to make sure we keep a dataframe with the columns equal to `['VAF']`.  Otherwise, if we used `df['VAF']`we would return a series object whose name is `'VAF'`.  Also, `pandas.Series` doesn't have a `set_index` method and `pandas.DataFrame` does.

```
df[['VAF']].set_index(idx)

                         VAF
ID                          
chr1-115227855-T-C  0.002662
chr1-115227856-C-T  0.001545
chr1-115227857-C-T  0.001236
chr1-115227858-A-T  0.001793
chr1-115227880-C-T  0.001115
```

We could have done this to get a series

```
df.set_index(idx)['VAF']

ID
chr1-115227855-T-C    0.002662
chr1-115227856-C-T    0.001545
chr1-115227857-C-T    0.001236
chr1-115227858-A-T    0.001793
chr1-115227880-C-T    0.001115
Name: VAF, dtype: float64
```

See!  Same data, but now a series whose name is `'VAF'`